# How to set data fetched from database in Ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I use CKEditor to insert some content in 'wysiwyg' mode. I input "Hello World!" in the editor, and the real context inserted into database is

```
"<p>Hello World!</p>".
```

Now I load the data from database and set it into CKEditor:

```
String content = loadFromDb();
// --> <p>Hello, world!</p>
CKEditor.instances['test'].setData(content);
```

But in the CKEditor, it shows:

```
<p>Hello, world!</p>
```

in 'wysiwyg' mode. When I click 'source' button, it shows:

```
<p> &lt;p&rt;Hello, world!&lt;/p&gt;</p>
```

How can I set the data as html code, and I can see only "Hello, world!" in CKEditor on 'wysiwyg' mode?

Do I need to use some type of Html encoder?

PS: I have reposted this question because no one answered it in 2012 and it was very important for me to get the answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `insertHtml` function.

`CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml( '<p>Hello, world!</p>' );`

The documentation can be found [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml)